# Metrics to estimate K in Kmeans

Tags: python, k-means

I'm trying to estimate number of K in Kmeans using Elbow and BIC methods.X is multidimensional array of data points (100000 data points X 100 features)
Here is the code I use for Elbow:

```
Ks = [40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]
ds = []
for K in Ks:
    cls = MiniBatchKMeans(K, batch_size =1000, random_state = 101)
    for i in xrange(0, len(X), 1000):
        chunk = newvec[i:i + 1000]
        cls.partial_fit(chunk)
    ds.append(cls.inertia_)   
plt.plot(Ks, ds)  
plt.xlabel('Value of K')
plt.ylabel('Distortion')
plt.show()
```

The code I use for BIC is coming from here[by Prabhath Nanisetty](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90769/using-bic-to-estimate-the-number-of-k-in-kmeans)

Here are plots I'm getting using each one of these methods:
[image: Elbow method]
[image: BIC method]

What is the right K value to use? Are those the right metrics to use for my dataset based on these results.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your dataset has way too many dimensions and risks suffering from [the curse of dimensionality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65379/machine-learning-curse-of-dimensionality-explained).

But to answer your question, at least from the elbow method, it seems like K = 90 going by the elbow method. To use the BIC method you look at the highest value (according to that particular implementation; some implementations reverse the signs). This makes it a bit more ambiguous, but appears that after K = 60, all of them perform almost equally well.

You can also take a look at [this article on the same topic](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/finding-the-k-in-k-means-clustering/). It introduces another method to estimate K, the Gap method. I'd say run one more metric to break ties and then select the best K returned by 2 or more out of the 3 metrics.